# How To Enable Tool tip Hints

Tags: interface

Not sure what I did but I no longer see the keyboard shortcuts for something when I hover over the TMenu. For example when in edit mode if I would hover over Loop Cut it used to say "Shortcut: Spacebar, Ctrl R" and now it just says "Cut mesh loop and slide it". Still to new to have everything memorized and really rely on these hints to keep me moving forward. Anyone know what I need to enable to show these again?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Edit --> Blender Preferences -->** Enable **Tooltips**

Also, holding Alt while Tooltips are disabled forces the tooltips to show.

(I am using Blender 2.8 by the way)

Comment: Thanks for replying mrpenguinb, I thought that too but no. I found the problem and it makes no sense. To note I do have "Tooltips" enabled. Now if I go to keymap and change Spacebar Actions to Search I lose the shortcut. Even trying to click Alt does not force it to display, regardless if Tooltips is enabled or not. So long as I have chosen "Search for the spacebar action the keyboard shortcut refuses to show. If I choose Play or Tools it works just fine. This has got to be a bug doesnt it?

Comment: I set the spacebar to be search, and now I have the same issue as you! Turns out you found a bug. Good job.
If you change your spacebar binding manually, then you can search normally AND get the tooltips. This seems to be a bug with the GUI option that is provided.

Comment: Thanks, yes I have a work around. No clue how to report this to the developers though?

Comment: I assume this is the place to go: https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/project/2/type/Bug/
It seems like the right place to report it. You should try and describe the problem thoroughly so the devs (or anyone else) can replicate it. Should be relatively easy to report.

Comment: Tips + general info about reporting bugs for Blender: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Bug_Reports